# How the value of a variable j increments to 6

Tags: java

Actually the purpose of the whole code is to get input values (0 or 1) in an array then check entered array for 6 continuous 0's then insert '1'after each 6  consecutive 0's. I found that this block

```
if(j>5){
        shift(i+6);
        bits[i+6] = 1;
        count+=1;
        System.out.println(count);
}
```

is executed even if there is no 6 consecutive 0's in the entered array. Then to check the problem. I added this statement

```
 System.out.println("ABHINAV " + j );
```

and here is output:-

```
Entered Bits are:  
 1
 0
 1
 0
 1
 0
 1
 0
 1
 0
ABHINAV 0
ABHINAV 1
ABHINAV 0
ABHINAV 1
ABHINAV 0
ABHINAV 1
ABHINAV 0
ABHINAV 1
ABHINAV 0
ABHINAV 6
```

I found the problem - the variable 'j' increments to 6 and hence the 'if' block is entered. My Question is:-

**How 'j' is getting incremented to 6 (as you can see the last line of the output snap).**

How this problem can be solved. What I am doing wrong.

Here is the whole code

```
class Stuff{
    public static final int LENGTH=6;                  
    public int count=0;             
    int n;
    public int bits[] = new int[40]; 
    Scanner inputs = new Scanner(System.in);
    Stuff(int x){
        n=x;
    }
    public void input(){
        for(int i=0 ; i<n ; i++){
            bits[i] = inputs.nextInt();
        }
    }
    public void len_check(){
        int j=0;
        for(int i = 0 ; i< n ; i++){
                j=0;
                while(bits[i+j] == 0 && j<LENGTH){
                    j+=1;
                }
                System.out.println("ABHINAV " + j );
                if(j>5){
                    shift(i+6);
                    bits[i+6] = 1;
                    count+=1;
                    System.out.println(count);
                }
        }
    }   
    public void shift(int u){
        for(int i=n ; i>= u ;i--){
            bits[i+1] = bits[i];
        }
    }   
    public void display(){
        for(int i=0 ; i<n+count ; i++){
            System.out.println(" " + bits[i]);
        }
    }
}

class Problem{
    public static void main(String args[]){
        int n;
        Scanner inputs = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("\nEnter bit stream length");
        n = inputs.nextInt();
        Stuff stuff = new Stuff(n);
        System.out.println("Now Enter the bits: ");
        stuff.input();                  // Enter the bit stream 
        System.out.println("Entered Bits are:  ");
        stuff.display();    
        stuff.len_check();
        System.out.println("Altered Bits are: ");
        stuff.display();
    }
}
```

Comment: Please include **Output** as text, not an Image

Comment: Dont talk about problems you already solved. Just focus on the **real** question. Why should we waste our time reading about a problem that you fixed yourself?

Comment: @GhostCat Problem isn't solved. I mentioned the question as a bold text.

Comment: Just doing a manual run on paper should tell you why this is happening. Why do you need human debuggers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because the input is only 10 positions long, after the 10 first values the array `bits` is filled with `0` (standard value). 
It is working as programmed, finding 6 `0` starting at position 10.

It should stop when reaching the position `n - 5`, e.g:

```
...
int j = 0;
for (int i = 0 ; i< n-5 ; i++) {
    j = 0;
...
```

Answer (score 1):

the bits variable was instantiated with the length 40,

```
public int bits[] = new int[40];
```

this so the bits[] were an array of zeros with length 40. After that the first ten elements ere replaced by the inputs. Here's the array:

```
index 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 ...
value 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  ...
```

This code:

```
while(bits[i+j] == 0 && j<LENGTH){
    j+=1;
}
```

when i=9, it increments j 6 times because bits[9] to bits[14] are 0.

Answer (score 1):

`bits` is an int array of length 40 so it's full of 0 after what you have scanned for System.in.

When i = n-1, you check the last digit you entered which is 0 and all the next one are 0 so j increments to 6.

Answer (score 0):

```
 for(int i = 0 ; i< n ; i++){
        j=0;
        while(bits[i+j] == 0 && j<LENGTH){
            j+=1;
        }
```

This will just set j to 6 right away. Use an if instead:

```
     if(bits[i+j] == 0 && j<LENGTH){
          j+=1;
     }
```